# datasource vs simple connection database

Tags: java, .net, database, connection, datasource

What would be the best approach?, I need to connect many remote databases to resolve many requests from a Restful web service. I was thinking two solutions:

1. One datasource per remote database, and the connection to each datasource will be like a singleton pattern.
2. One simple connection per remote database, well just a singleton pattern to connect with each database.

One example of the first approach is like this (vía msdn):

```
import java.sql.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;

public class connectDS {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  // Declare the JDBC objects.
  Connection con = null;
  CallableStatement cstmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;

  try {
     // Establish the connection. 
     SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
     ds.setUser("UserName");
     ds.setPassword("*****");
     ds.setServerName("localhost");
     ds.setPortNumber(1433); 
     ds.setDatabaseName("AdventureWorks");
     con = ds.getConnection();

     // Execute a stored procedure that returns some data.
     cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call dbo.uspGetEmployeeManagers(?)}");
     cstmt.setInt(1, 50);
     rs = cstmt.executeQuery();

     // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
     while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("EMPLOYEE: " + rs.getString("LastName") + 
           ", " + rs.getString("FirstName"));
        System.out.println("MANAGER: " + rs.getString("ManagerLastName") + 
           ", " + rs.getString("ManagerFirstName"));
        System.out.println();
     }
  }

  // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
  catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally {
     if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
     if (cstmt != null) try { cstmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
     if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
     System.exit(1);
  }
 }
}
```

For the second approach the singleton example could be:

```
public java.sql.Connection conn;
private static Statement statement;

public static MysqlConnect db;

private MysqlConnect() {
    String url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "Banco";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "123456";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        this.conn = (java.sql.Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
        System.out.println("Connected to DataBase: " + dbName);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Error Inesperado en MysqlConnect" + sqle.toString());
    }
}

/**
 *Method for connect to a database
 * @return MysqlConnect Database connection object
 */
public static synchronized MysqlConnect getDbCon() {
    if ( db == null ) {
        try {
            db = new MysqlConnect();
            statement = db.conn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MysqlConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Connection to DB: OK");
    return db;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the relationship between your databases and  your queries.  If you have lots of queries going to a single database, for example a user database, then you will need more than one connection to it or else you will end up with your threads blocking on that resource.

The most flexible way of doing this is to have a connection pool for each remote database, and configure each so that they have a suitable number of connections available considering their likelihood to be queried during any single REST transaction.

A good place to start might be to look at the Tomcat datasource pooling.  Note that you can use it regardless of if you use Tomcat as your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

A `Connection` can not be used concurrently by several threads, while a `DataSource` can.